# Gnuplot labels from two columns

Tags: gnuplot

I need to get 2 columns for a label

The code attached below will give labels from column 4. I would like to get labels from columns 4 and 1.

```
 plot 'datafile' using 1:(0.5 * $2):4 with labels font "arial,11" tc lt 2
```

Datafile:

```
1 4 5 6
2 5 6 9
```

Comment: Please provide some example data. What do you want to do with the labels from col4 and col1, simply merge?

Comment: Yes, simply merge, just next to each other. I need that just for information, it is not necessary to get nice plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, you are looking for something like this:
simply merge your (numeric) columns or stringcolumns (check `help strcol`) in a `sprintf()` expression. Check `help sprintf` and `help format_specifiers`.

**Script:**

```
### plot labels from multiple columns
reset session

$Data <<EOD
 A   1   9   11
 B   2   8   22
 C   3   7   33
 D   4   6   44
 E   5   5   55
EOD

set offset 1,1,1,1
set key noautotitle

plot $Data u 2:3:(sprintf("%s-%d",strcol(1),column(4))) w labels point pt 7 lc "red" offset 0,1
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]